# get multiple checkbox vlaues

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the following the check boxes how to get only the checked boxes values in one line in this format  CheckBox1value,Checksalevalue etc..
thanks in advance

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">
 Service 
</label>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="cr-styled">
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" value="a"  runat="server"  />
<i class="fa"></i>
</label>
Sale 
<label class="cr-styled">
<asp:CheckBox ID="Checksale" value="b" runat="server" />
<i class="fa"></i>
</label>
Rental
<label class="cr-styled">
<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkrent" value="c" runat="server" />
</label>
                                               
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ok fine, then what is your question? why can't you use a checkedbox list instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code :

```
   for (int i=0; i<checkboxlist1.Items.Count; i++)
   {
         if (checkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected)
         {
               Message.Text += checkboxlist1.Items[i].Text + "<br />";
          }
   }
```

Refer to [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
foreach(Control cntrl in form.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
     string value = cntrl.Value;
     //do something with value
}
```

Note- Code is not tested. May have some syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string strValues = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in CheckBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
           strValues += item.SelectedValue + ","; 
        }
    }
```